# Can't add a GwtQuery (1.0.6) DragAndDropCellTree in GWT (2.7) GWTP (1.5) project

Tags: java, gwt, gwtp, gwtquery

**I'm trying to add a [GwtQuery DragAndDropCellTree](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers#DragAndDropCellTree_,_DragAndDropCellBrowser_and_DragAndDropNode) to MyView.java in my GWTP project.  But I can't GWT Compile it:**

```
Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImplStandard'    
  [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellBasedWidgetImplStandard.java'
    [ERROR] Line 54: Referencing method 'com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/EventListener;)': unable to resolve method in class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM'    
[ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly    
[ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.user.User' either directly or indirectly
Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImplTrident'
  [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellBasedWidgetImplTrident.java'
    [ERROR] Line 98: Referencing method 'com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/EventListener;)': unable to resolve method in class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM'    
...
[ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellBasedWidgetImpl.java'
    [ERROR] Line 46: Rebind result 'com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.CellBasedWidgetImplTrident' could not be found
Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery'
  [ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/query/client/GQuery.java'
    [ERROR] Line 469: The method f(Object[]) is ambiguous for the type Function
```

If I try to navigate to MyView in dev mode:

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellBasedWidgetImplStandard.java'    
  [ERROR] Line 54: Referencing method 'com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Event;Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/EventListener;)': unable to resolve method in class 'com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM'    
[ERROR] - Member 'null' in JSNI reference '@com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM::null' could not be found; expect subsequent failures
```

**Upon de-bugging into the DragAndDropCellTree, I arrive at line 624-625 in CellTree:**

`this.style = resources.cellTreeStyle();
 this.style.ensureInjected();`

**The Style gets set 'successfully', but its `injected` field is `false`.  So `ensureInjected()` does not return (it must throw an exception).**

I might be doing something wrong with the TreeViewModel and AbstractCell that I implemented to construct my DragAndDropCellTree with... I'm not sure.

Any ideas on how to solve this, or anything else to look into?
Thanks.

**Edit:  my pom.xml (see DND dependency towards bottom, and the repository right above it, per [DragAndDropPlugin configuration](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers#Configuration)):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.priorigram</groupId>
    <artifactId>PrioriGram</artifactId>
    <version>0</version>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>GWTP Basic</name>

    <properties>
        <!-- client -->
        <gwt.version>2.7.0</gwt.version>
        <gwtp.version>1.5.1</gwtp.version>
        <gin.version>2.1.2</gin.version>
        <gwt.style>OBF</gwt.style>

        <!-- maven -->
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>

        <target.jdk>1.7</target.jdk>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <outputDirectory>${webappDirectory}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/com/priorigram/client/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${target.jdk}</source>
                    <target>${target.jdk}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- GWT -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <strict>true</strict>

                    <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
                    <mode>htmlunit</mode>
                    <includes>**/*GwtTest.java</includes>

                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>

                    <runTarget>index.html</runTarget>
                    <module>com.priorigram.PrioriGram</module>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
         <id>plugins</id>
         <url>http://gwtquery-plugins.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
       </repository>
   </repositories>

    <dependencies>        
        <!-- DND -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>gquery-dnd-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GWT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- GWTP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwtplatform</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtp-mvp-client</artifactId>
            <version>${gwtp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>gin</artifactId>
            <version>${gin.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Edit: From my .gwt.xml:**

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
<inherits name="com.gwtplatform.mvp.MvpWithEntryPoint"/>
<inherits name='gwtquery.plugins.droppable.Droppable'/>
```

Comment: This looks like a module inheritance problem.  Would you post the *.gwt.xml file?

Comment: @SimonDeWolf Thanks, but I think you are looking at the Droppable Plugin?  That is different from the DragAndDrop Plugin that I linked to for DragAndDropCellTree; 1.0.6 is the latest DragAndDrop Plugin for GWT 2.5+: https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers#Configuration

Comment: @SimonDeWolf just added my pom.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code for `CellBasedWidgetImplStandard.java` I can see exactly why it's failing.  The second argument it's passing to `DOM.dispatchEvent()` is:

```
Lcom/google/gwt/user/client/Element;
```

While in the latest version of GWT, that method's second parameter is:

```
Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/Element;
```

Note the difference in package name between the two.  This was a change made in GWT 2.6 (if I recall correctly), so I think the solution here is to find an updated version of the DnD library.  Maybe this one fits the bill:

https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtquery-droppable-plugin

Comment: Thanks for this!  Looks like you are correct about that DOM.dispatchEvent() call.  The ArcBees Github project (https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtquery-droppable-plugin) you referred to have worked out too!  I'm about to make a separate Answer here with more details for getting that setup, but giving this the Answer Acceptance as it was the initial heart of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

As my comment on @Simon DeWolf 's Accepted Answer said, here are more details on getting a GwtQuery DragAndDropCellTree to instantiate and GWT compile.  His Answer has the reasons this solution is necessary beyond what I described attempting in this Question.

- These details apply if your GWT project is a Maven project:  They include adding [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/) as a Maven repository in order to use the updated version of [gwtquery-droppable-plugin](https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtquery-droppable-plugin) (pretty easy)
- But you can always do the barebones approach to download that Github source, and compile it into a .jar to add to you project's classpath

  1. Make the updated version of [gwtquery-droppable-plugin](https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtquery-droppable-plugin) a Maven dependency in your project.  These directions are for doing that with [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/).  Add this to your pom.xml:

`

```
<repositories>
    <!-- for com.github dependencies (doc @ https://jitpack.io/) -->
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- GwtQuery - these dependencies must be before gwt dependency (these override/replace some things in gwt) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.Arcbees</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwtquery-droppable-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>486057e</version>
    </dependency>
     ...
</dependencies>`
```

2. Add this to your .gwt.xml Module file:

   `<inherits name='gwtquery.plugins.droppable.Droppable'/>

   <!-- to prevent the GWT error [compile error, I think],
         "IFrame linker is deprecated; consider switching to the xsiframe linker",
        after making ArcBees' gwtquery-droppable-plugin a Maven dependency (from Github via JitPack)
        and instantiating a DragAndDropCellTree (in [db0f3c6]).
        *See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/OiMZA-6oCDc -->
   <add-linker name="xsiframe" />`
3. You should now be able to declare a DragAndDropCellTree
4. To then instantiate the DragAndDropCellTree, I have these suggestions to break into learning that:

   - I suggest following the [gwtquery-arcbees-plugin sample](https://github.com/ArcBees/gwtquery-droppable-plugin/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/gwtquery/plugins/droppable/client/permissionmanagersample/PermissionManagerSample.java)
   - Following that may be a bit dense as there is no doc besides source comments...  I suggest making a native GWT CellTree (which DragAndDropCellTree extends) first, and then converting it to DragAndDropCellTree to subsequently transition more easily in following the gwtquery-arcbees-plugin sample
   - To start with a CellTree, I suggest following Code Example #1 ([CellTreeExample.java](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/user/javadoc/com/google/gwt/examples/cellview/CellTreeExample.java)) from the [GWT CellTree doc](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets.html#celltree)